# How to say "current surface maps" in Portuguese?

Tags: tradução-inglês, tradução

I want to find weather map forecasts with iso-pressure lines and cold and warm fronts, such as [this one from the US government](https://www.weather.gov/oun/sfcmaps):

[image: Map of surface currents in the US]

Warm fronts are in red with triangles, cold fronts are in blue with semicircles.

What is the name in Portuguese?

Comment: Pensei que fosse o mar a primeira vista. Credo.

Comment: http://www.inmet.gov.br/portal/index.php?r=clima/prev_estocastica e aqui: http://www.inmet.gov.br/portal/arq/clima/prognostico-climatico-trimestral/pc1901.pdf

Comment: I think the word "current" stands for "flow", "airstream" or something like that in the context. If not it would be "current surface maps" I guess. Well, if so, the translation people may give you may be incorrect if they translate it to "contemporary", "present", "live" (atual in Portuguese). The difference between adjective order in English and Portuguese is very tricky even for experienced English knowers. For me the translation would be just "Cartas de Superfície".

Comment: @Luciano    Just follow [**this link**](https://www.weather.gov/oun/sfcmaps) and you'll see the OP meant "current surface maps".  I've edited the question.

Comment: É correto utilizar traduções de ingles neste forum? Nao consegue encontrar noutro ?

Comment: @CIMend É possível que não seja este o fórum apropriado. Qual fórum sugere?

Answer (score 3):

In Brazilian portugueses, literally you can say

> mapas atuais da superfície

to be sure about the context, I searched some meteorological pages in portuguese like [this](https://www.esa.int/SPECIALS/Eduspace_Weather_PT/SEMC86OC02G_0.html)

Comment: Creio eu que o mais adequado seria `mapa meteorológico atual da superfície`, sendo as setas vermelhas as `ondas de calor` e as azuis `ondas frias` (ou correntes frias)

Answer (score 3):

I've seen it called "**mapa de superfície atual**" or **"carta de superfície atual"** in weather forecast sites. It shows meteorological conditions on surface level (which is not to be confused with sea level) at a specific point in time.  You can also see forecast surface maps for, say, the next morning. There are also "mapas de altitude".

You can find such maps in Portuguese at **INPE-Cartas de Superfície** (Instituto Nacional de Pesquisas Espaciais)

> - [**The Mixed Surface Analysis**](https://www.wunderground.com/maps/current-weather/mixed-surface-analysis) map shows **a comprehensive analysis of current conditions and fronts at ground level** using radar and infrared satellite imagery. The Surface Analysis loop animation shows sequential maps at 3 hour intervals for the past 18 hours. A surface weather analysis is a special type of weather map that provides a view of weather elements over a geographical area at a specified time based on information from ground-based weather stations. Weather maps are created by plotting or tracing the values of relevant quantities such as sea level pressure, temperature, and cloud cover onto a geographical map to help find synoptic scale features such as weather fronts.

[image]

**The above map shows that "current" means "at this moment", not "air current" or any kind of stream.**

References:

1- [**Carta de Superfície**](http://tempo.cptec.inpe.br/cartas.php?tipo=Superficie)

2- [**Current Surface Map**](https://www.weather.gov/oun/sfcmaps)

I've edited and hope this settles any existing doubts about what "current" means in this context.

Comment: Yes, that website shows what I want for Brazil. I could not find an equivalent in Portugal with those terms, might the old continent have a different expression?

Comment: @miguelmorin Perhaps such visualizations are used more often for regions with large areas. I could find some examples from Portugal, sometimes with the additional qualification "sinóptico", denoting something in the lines of a summarized overview, such as in [Cartas sinópticas de superfície](http://navegadormensal.com/meteo/cartas/).

Comment: I don't really know the name for this in European Portuguese. But if these resources exist, your best bet is looking in IPMA (Instituto Português do Mar e Atmosfera): http://www.ipma.pt/ (available [in English](http://www.ipma.pt/en/index.html)) ; this site used to be meteo.pt .

Comment: @Centaurus, esta resposta foi muito boa. Olha que tentei pesquisar no google e não fui capaz de encontrar.

Comment: @miguelmorin   "imho I believe the solution..."   would be a more polite manner of expressing an opinion which, by the way, I don't share.

Comment: @miguelmorin    In pt-BR, he map in question is a "mapa de superfície".  When you add the adjective "atual", you mean that the "mapa de superfície" is "atual".  Therefore, "mapa de superfície atual".  "Mapa de superfície" is a set phrase and I don't think an adjective can fit in.

Comment: I can say "mapa de superfície atual", "mapa de superfície de ontem" or "mapa de superfície de amanhã", but I wouldn't say "mapa atual de superfície" just as I wouldn't say "mapa de ontem de superfície" or "mapa de amanhã de superfície" either.

Comment: I think you are mistaken.  "current", in this case, means "atual".  What you you call "airstream" is simply "jet stream" in English.  On surface level, it's simply "wind".

Comment: See [Current US Surface Weather Map](https://weather.com/maps/currentusweather)

Comment: [**SURFACE WEATHER ANALYSIS CHART**](http://www.meteor.wisc.edu/~hopkins/aos100/sfc-anl.htm)      Historically, the surface weather map was the first weather map produced, dating back to the early 19th century. Even today, it remains the one of the most useful charts for ascertaining current weather conditions just above the surface of the earth for a large geographic region.

Comment: A downvote.  Not everybody seems to accept my answer, despite all the evidence and links I've provided.

Comment: Thanks for your perseverance! You've convinced me that "current" means "at the moment" instead of "airstream" and I deleted my comments. However, I cannot find the relevant maps for Portugal with that term, but I can find some with "análise sinótica." I cannot find current surface maps for Europe with the English term, which would also solve the problem.